# Setting up AngularJS HTML5 routing

Tags: html, angularjs

I have set up a local version of AngularJS using MAMP on my Mac. I have enabled the HTML5 mode using the locationProvider so that urls no longer have the # in them.

To do this though I have added:

```
<base href="http://localhost:8888/AngularJS/app/">
```

to the top of the `index.html` page.

This gets things working... BUT ONLY if the url in the browser matches PERFECTLY (e.g. correct case and correct trailing slash). Otherwise it redirects you to the sever root at localhost:8888 but STILL shows the AngularJS app, so it's client side history change rather than an actual sever redirect.

I get the feeling I am doing something wrong... Is there a better way to get this working?

Comment: Please provide your angular route config code. You should not need to change the `<base>`.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could share your angular module configuration file to see exactly how your route is set up.

I would recommend making your base tag to be relative to the domain, which makes it environment free and safer for deployments to new environements `<base href="/AngularJS/app/">`

The server should be configured to gracefully handle routes that fall off of the required path. Meaning if you access `http://localhost:8888/AngularJS/ZZZ`, it should probably redirect to a 404 Page Not Found (after all, that is a bad route, correct?).

Finally, to support deep linking into your app with Angular's HTML5 mode, your server should catch all url globs which are deeper than `/AngularJS/app/` and prefix a hash to them, allowing your server routing to not break, and to pass the hash into Angular.

Specifically, if you have an HTML5 route such as `/AngularJS/app/login` or `/AngularJS/app/page/1`, and the user enters `/AngularJS/app/page/1` into the browser, you can make the server redirect to `/AngularJS/app/#/page/1` which Angular will recognize the hash and convert it to an HTML5 route (thus supporting deep linking, and assuming it's a correctly configured route in Angular).

I'm doing this exact thing in an HTML5 app, but we also have [multiple] dynamic slugs in our Angular router, so our server is configured for scenarios that fall short of a valid route, and scenarios that deep link past the base route of our HTML5 app.

Regarding the trailing slash issue, you will probably have to find a solution with .htaccess from the sound of it (probably by coercing it when absent).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following virtualhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-app

    DocumentRoot /path/to/app

    <Directory /path/to/app>
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I've tried this in my top level folder 'angularjs' which contains the 'app' folder, but I get an error that VirtualHost is not allowed here, and checking the server config, I have override allow all. Any ideas? Code is here: http://pastebin.com/LfVKfhnm

Comment: Virtual host needs to be in a specific location (Mac /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf, Ubuntu /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com) https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_leopard.php